# 'float' object is not iterable in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class TransactionHistoryListSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerVisit

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        price = 0
        package_price = booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance).values_list(
            "package__test__test_mrp", flat=True
        )[0]
        for price in package_price:
            pass

        return {
            "visit_id": instance.id,
            "customer_name": {
                "salutation": instance.customer.salutation,
                "first_name": instance.customer.first_name,
                "middle_name": instance.customer.middle_name,
                "last_name": instance.customer.last_name,
            },
            "dob": instance.customer.date_of_birth,
            "amount": sum([k.amount for k in booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance)])
            + (price if price else 0),
            "discount": sum([k.discount for k in booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance)]),
            "paid_amount": sum([k.amount for k in payment_models.Payment.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance)]),
        }
```

here **tes_mrp** is float type.
I searched and got solution to use list comprehension but still not working. I tried `[[price] for price in package_price]`, `for price in package_price: a = list(str(price))` but still getting float object is not iterable. Surely i am doing something wrong. Can somebody help. Thank you !!

Comment: You should show the traceback to the line that exhibits the error. There are many places in your code that could do that.

Comment: My bad I will take care of it from next time. It is causing in this line - for price in package_price:

Answer (score 0):

> It is causing in this line - for price in package_price:

Right, well, that's because you're doing `.values_list(..., flat=True)`, which returns a list, and then indexing it with `[0]`, so you get the first value. `package_price` thus is indeed a float and as the error says, you can't iterate over a single float.

That particular bit would thus be fixed simply by taking out that `[0]`.

Your code can be simplified to not repeat the queries and to use Django's aggregates:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    bookings = booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance)
    payments = payment_models.Payment.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance)

    package_price = bookings.values_list("package__test__test_mrp", flat=True).first()
    booking_amounts = bookings.aggregate(
        price_sum=Sum("amount"),
        discount_sum=Sum("discount"),
    )
    payment_amounts = payments.aggregate(
        payment_sum=Sum("amount"),
    )

    return {
        "visit_id": instance.id,
        "customer_name": {
            "salutation": instance.customer.salutation,
            "first_name": instance.customer.first_name,
            "middle_name": instance.customer.middle_name,
            "last_name": instance.customer.last_name,
        },
        "dob": instance.customer.date_of_birth,
        "amount": (booking_amounts.get("price_sum") or 0) + package_price,
        "discount": booking_amounts.get("discount_sum") or 0,
        "paid_amount": payment_amounts.get("payment_sum") or 0,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but now I am getting this error - float object is not subscriptable in this line - package_price = package_price_record[0] if package_price_record else 0

Comment: My bad, fixed now.

Comment: Yeah it is working but could you just confirm one more thing. Every time when it iterates - is it taking the test_mrp[0]. Because this is what i have to do as test is m2m field.

Comment: The iteration order of an m2m field is not guaranteed, so you'll get _some_ Test object. The behavior is the same as with the `[0]` though.